# Headphones provide only background sound

Tags: audio, headphones

This is actually a bit weird problem. Whenever I plug in my earphones on my PC, I hear only the background sound. But if I press and hold the receiver button on my earphones, I hear both vocal and background sound. But when I plug the earphones halfway through, I hear both vocal and background sound but in mono, no stereo.
This problem is killing me... I need a solution! I didn't have the problem before...
 * I tried cleaning the port on my laptop
 * I tried reinstalling my sound drivers

Answer (score 0):

This is typically used for VOIP calls I would suspect (where it automatically reduces the volume so you can hear the other person).

First off, your jack plug has 2 black lines. This indicates stereo. If you only press it in half way through, only one of these makes a contact (hence the mono sound).

```
Open Control Panel -> Sound

Click on the Communications tab

Select `Do Nothing`
```

Comment: I tried it before, but didn't work... :(

Comment: Does this issue only occur with these headphones?

Comment: No, any type of phone headphones...

Comment: So, what happens if you roll the drivers back, or even a System Restore to before the issue?

Comment: I tried everything, buddy..
I mean everything you mentioned...